# What is wrong with this Python regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Given a string, I want to find all the substrings consisting of two or three '4,'.

For example, given '1,4,3,2,1,1,4,4,3,2,1,4,4,3,2,1,4,4,4,3,2,'
I want to get ['4,4,', '4,4,', '4,4,4'].

```
str_ = '1,4,4,3,2,1,1,4,4,3,2,1,4,4,3,2,1,4,4,3,2,'
m = re.findall(r"(4,){2,3}", str_)
```

what I get is :
['4,', '4,', '4,', '4,']

what's wrong?

It seems to me that the parenthesis wrapping '4,' is interpreted as grouping but not telling Python '4' and ',' should occur together. However, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Solved, I should use the non-capturing version of regular parentheses

Comment: Maybe just use `r"(4,)+"`?

Comment: @pawamoy that won't work, the parenthesis plays a role of identifying the groups but binding characters together. We should use (?:4,) instead of (4,)

Comment: @user3101491 If you solved the issue, write it as an answer so it might help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use non-capturing group (online version of [this regex here](https://regex101.com/r/8xXQKB/2)):

```
import re

s = '1,4,3,2,1,1,4,4,3,2,1,4,4,3,2,1,4,4,4,3,2,'

print(re.findall(r'(?:4,?){2,3}', s))
```

Prints:

```
['4,4,', '4,4,', '4,4,4,']
```

EDIT:

Edited regex to capture 2 or 3 elements `"4,"`

Comment: `(?:(?:4,){1,2}4)` would handle the commas more precisely

Comment: Though then that could incorrectly match `4,4,44`. Maybe `(?<=^|,)((?:4,){1,2})(?=,|$)` then?